# Custom Dashboard Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

I am trying to create a custom dashboard interface, where users can remove certain things from the main page they don't want to see and store it via LocalStorage to pull up for future use.

Basically, I have a preloaded list in localstorage containing all of the possible elements, If a user clicks the 'X' to remove that element, this function below will match and remove it from the list, then re-save the updated list to localstorage. Elements are hidden by attaching the bootstrap class 'd-none' to target elements.

The problem I am having is that while elements can successfully be removed and saved, I cannot find a solution to push the still visible ones up to the top if things above are removed. Elements are in the same row, but different col-6's.

I have attached 2 screenshots to help visualize. One with half the elements removed, and one of how I am laying out as a grid.

As you can see, when I removed 3 elements, the ones still visible are in their original place. Does anyone have a solution to force them up? I understand the 'hidden' elements are still in their place and that is why I am left with more ugly empty space than my Animal Crossing house!

```
    //hideThis handles hiding cards by ID
    const hideThis = (id) => {
        //the element to hide
        let targetDiv = document.getElementById(id);
        //hide it
        targetDiv.classList.add('d-none');
        //for each of the to show elements
        for (let i = 0; i < elementsToShow.length; i++) {
            //if that element is equal to the target ID
            if (elementsToShow[i] === targetDiv.id) {
                // remove it
                elementsToShow.splice(i, 1);
                localStorage.setItem('shownElements', JSON.stringify(elementsToShow));
            }
        }
        console.log(elementsToShow);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('shownElements'));
    };
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the d-none class is not being added to the the class ["col-12", "col-md-6"], the d-none class is being added to what is inside the these classes ["col-12", "col-md-6"], and these classes are still present there occupying the space.

To solve this issue what you can do is that use the closest() method in javascript.

e.g.
target.closest("col-12").classList.add("d-none")

Comment: Another alternate solution is to assign id's to the div containing the "col-6 col-md-6" and then try to add the class "d-none" there

Comment: Zuhaib! This solution worked! You are right I was hiding the card itself but not its parent container. Viola! It works!